# slave replication stopped working

Tags: mysql, replication

This morning my slave stopped working..

```
Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
Slave_IO_Running: Yes
Slave_SQL_Running: No
```

> Last_SQL_Error: Could not execute Update_rows event on table
>   dynaccount.account; Can't find record in 'account', Error_code: 1032;
>   handler error HA_ERR_KEY_NOT_FOUND; the event's master log
>   mysql-bin.000025, end_log_pos 802331975

## Restoring slave

```
- Master
# mysqldump -u root -pxxx --single-transaction --hex-blob --routines --triggers --events --quick --add-drop-database --extended-insert --databases my_db | gzip > /root/dump.sql.gz
# scp -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' /root/dump.sql.gz root@remote.com:/root

- Slave
# mysql -u root_slave -pxxx -e "stop slave; reset master"

# pv /root/dump.sql.gz | gunzip | mysql -u root_slave -pxxx
# mysql -u root_slave -pxxx -e "start slave"
# mysql -u root_slave -pxxx -e "show slave status\G"
```

After restoring the slave I keep getting the same error?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `--master-data` to the mysqldump. That way the change of slave position to where you did the mysqldump gets executed when you load it.

Comment: you saved my day :P